# How to "Avoid mutating a prop directly" in a recursive component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I understand the concept: the child works on its own copy of the prop data, and when it's changed it it can `$emit` that change so the parent can update itself.

However, I'm dealing with a recursive tree structure, e.g. a filesystem, is a good analogy.

```
[
 { type: 'dir', name: 'music', children: [
    { type: 'dir', name: 'genres', children: [
       { type: 'dir', name: 'triphop', children: [
          { type: 'file', name: 'Portishead' },
          ...
       ]},
     ]}
   ]}
]}
```

I have a recursive component called `Thing` that takes a `childtree` *prop* and looks a bit like this:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="tree.name" />
  <thing v-for="childtree in tree.children" :tree="childtree" ></thing>
</template>
```

Modifying a name is obviously going to modify the prop directly, which is to be avoided, and Vue emits a warning about it.

However, the only way I can see to avoid that would be for each component to do a deep copy of `childtree`; then `$emit` a copy of our copy and have a `@input` (or such) copy it back to the original; all the way up the tree, which would then change the props all the way down the tree causing another deep copy of everything!

That feels like it's going to be really inefficient on a tree of any size.

Is there a better way? I know you can trick Vue into not issuing the error/warning [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5no0xepq/).

Comment: In your example 'trick' is ok and 'normal' is not, exactly because of the reasoning behind this warning; a prop is overwritten on component update. Two-way data flow (v-model in 'trick') may work against you on the large scale. One-way data flow ($emit or Vuex) is generally preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix for your problem is passing just event from the child component. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kv1w72pg/2/

```
<input @input="(e) => $emit('input', e.target.value)" />
```

That being said I highly suggest you use other solution such as:

1. Vuex,
2. Event bus

It will make code clear and ensure one source of truth.

Edit: In the case of recursive inheritance, using provide inject would be easier: https://jsfiddle.net/s0b9fpr8/4/

This way you provide a function that can change the state of base component to all children components (function must be injected).

Comment: Thanks. `$emit`: The issue is that the 'value' of the child is the child's own values and the entire subtree below it. Since javascript passes by reference, this would need to be a deep clone/copy at each stage (expensive, slow). Vuex, Event bus and Provide/Inject are all ways of sharing an object between components, but in a recursive situation each component instance needs to be dealing with a nested property, not the top level object. So in order to use those solutions it would need to maintain a list of keys to find itself - that would be v. hard to maintain if other nodes were changed.

Comment: It can use one object, what you need is to pass to nested instances their position on that object, so they know, which part of the object to change.

Comment: yeah, but that assumes their ancestral indexes won't change. e.g. an object that is found at root.a3.b2.c5 - if an element is inserted before a3, then a3 becomes a4. Or anywhere else in the chain.

Comment: This is not necessary, you can use something unique, like path: https://jsfiddle.net/7sojbcxk/4/

Answer (score 0):

**One-Way Data Flow**

Every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
>   if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
>   inside the child component will affect parent state.

**Here is an example with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)**

when we just [`clone`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#clone).

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var shallow = _.clone(objects);
console.log(shallow[0] === objects[0]);
// => true
```

When we use [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// => false
```

So, if you want to update any props value in your child component, you need to use [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) of lodash.

Comment: Thanks but cloneDeep is what I want to avoid. It means every node has to deep-clone the entire tree below it.

Comment: not really,in your last component [the input el] will implement the clone deep,where you want to change something without giving any clue to the parent component.

Comment: I need to change something at each and every level (e.g. directory name, in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's roughly how I've handled this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="myName" @input="updateParent()" />
    <thing v-for="(child, i) in myChildren" :key="child.uniqueId"
     @input="setChild(i, $event)"
     >
    </thing>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: ['node'],
data() {
  return {
     myName: this.node.name,
     myChildren: this.node.children.slice(0),
  };
},
methods: {
  updateParent() {
    this.$emit('input', {name: this.myName, children: this.myChildren});
  },
  setchild(i, newChild) {
    this.$set(this.myChildren, i, newChild);
  }
}
}
</script>
```

This means each node of the tree:

- works on it's own copy of 'name'
- holds its own array of children (even though the children are 'real' - they're references belonging to the object that is not 'ours' to change, but the array is ours).
- tells the parent to replace it when there's an update.
- listens for child nodes that have been updated.

This seems to work and seems to avoid mutating props. One thing not shown here, but I found was crucial, was setting a unique ID on each child. I did this by creating Ids sequentially from a global counter (on `$root`).